# Getting raw XML response from SoapHttpClientProtocol

Tags: c#, xml, soap-client

Calling a web service method causes an exception because of a malformed XML response and I need to locate the point of this formlessness and see the raw XML text to locate it.
I get the following exception:

```
There is an error in XML document (1, 2181004)
```

But I can't see the character(s) which cause the XML to be malformed. For a better description, I've a C# project which calls web service methods, by importing them via the automatically generated Reference.cs (SOAP). I use a derivation of SoapHttpClientProtocol class. Now I need to have this malformed XML response to see line 1, column 2181004 of it.
How is it possible?

### Update

Note the following code:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapRpcMethodAttribute("http://192.168.42.11/webService.php/Authenticate", RequestNamespace="udn:Behnama", ResponseNamespace="udn:Behnama")]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.SoapElementAttribute("return")]
public AuthenticationResult Authenticate(string username, string password, string domainName, bool RemoteAccess) {
  try
  {
    object[] results = this.Invoke("Authenticate", new object[] {
      username,
      password,
      domainName,
      RemoteAccess});
    return ((AuthenticationResult)(results[0]));
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    return null;
  }
}
```

This function is located in Reference.cs which is automatically generated by the Visual Studio from the web service report given by the server. When I try to step into the function Invoke, I get the following error message:

`Unable to automatically step into the server. Connecting to the server machine '192.168.42.11' failed. Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password. See help for more information.

The help button opens the following url:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/error-workgroup-remote-logon-failure?view=vs-2022&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev10IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk%2528VS.DEBUG.ERROR.WORKGROUP_REMOTE_LOGON_FAILURE%2529%3Bk%2528TargetFrameworkMoniker-%2522.NETFRAMEWORK%252cVERSION%253dV4.0%2522%2529%3Bk%2528DevLang-CSHARP%2529%26rd%3Dtrue

This is while my user is of group Administrators and I don't think the help is related. In server side, I see the following message in syslog:

`user authenticated successfully, session id 653465172c2c1`

So the username and password match what in database.
Then, when I close the message box, control continues on the first line after catch. The exception is of type System.InvalidOperationException with msg `There is an error in XML document (1, 2181004).` The _innerException member is `Value is either too large or too small for an Int32.`

This is all of what I get in details.

Comment: You can validate the xml using Visual Studio.  From menu : Project : Add New Item : Xml File.  Then paste the xml into view.  Errors will show like any compiler error.

Comment: This is not the problem. The problem is that I can't access the XML. Otherwise, I would refer to the column 2181004 and would know what is the problem.

Comment: The error says "There is an error in XML", not that xml cannot be found.  You need to validate the xml.

Comment: You really help by this comments! Hey! The XML is erroneous, okay? Now "I" need to see it to figure out what it is!

Comment: Use Visual Studio like I said in first comment.

Comment: I don't "have" it!

Comment: Please note that I'm not looking for an XML validator app. I'm looking for a way to see the XML document or have it as a file.

Comment: Try following : https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Comment: OMG! :|
See dear! I'm NOT looking for an XML validator! This is not my problem! My problem is how can I access the XML!

Comment: The error is not accessing the file.  The xml is not valid.

Comment: I know the error. For knowing the error cause, I need to SEE the XML to find out what's the problem or not?! In another words, what should I paste in the box in the link you sent when I don't have the XML?!

Comment: It's too simple not to understand!

Comment: The complete xml should be pasted in the box.

Comment: Sorry that you can't find what I say.

Comment: Why do you keep on saying the xml cannot be found?

Comment: It has a simple answer; because it can't be found!

Comment: It's not a file! It's dynamically created by server and sent to client.

Comment: The xml is in the content (body) of the response which is text.  To debug you can either put a break point in the code and copy the body of the response or save the body to a file so you can figure out the error.

Comment: I couldn't find the point to set the break. It seems that the exception is occurring in the soap libraries or somewhere out of my access. I just get the exception.

Comment: You may not be receiving a response because the connection never completed, the server never sent a response, or a timeout exception occurred.  It also could be to the network closing the connection due to the size of response exceeding 2MB.  Using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler may help to determine the failure.  The error is think is due to the size of the response.

Comment: This is what I thought at first, the size of the response. But, the exception is not of type timeout nor size. I investigated and found that the response may be as large as 2GB. Besides, the Visual Studio says that it receives the response, because it says that it includes and error on line 1, column 2181004.

Comment: I would put a break point on the request and then single step which should get you to the instruction where the response occurred.  What must be happening is there is a exception handler that is catching the response and preventing your break point from being reached.

Comment: The fail in not on a line of code. At least I couldn't find it. The soap infrastructure does the negotiation which is out of my source code.

Comment: Are you calling another c# project from you main project?  Make sure you are using the debug folder in child project and not the release folder so you can debug code.  Open the main project csproj file in notepad and make sure you are not using any "RELEASE" folders for child projects.  Use debug folders which has the debug pdb files.  If you are sending a request and not getting a response you are probably getting a time out exception when the connection does not complete.  Soap does not do any negotiations it is just the body of a http request.  The request does the negotiations.

Comment: I updated the question to include more details. The Solution Configurations box is on Debug, don't worry. But it can't step into the Invoke function.

Comment: Please, read about how to get the response of an HTTP request (which is more general than SOAP, but technically the same) in a string. This string will hold your complete XML, which can be stored in a file, or examined to see where the syntax goes wrong in this XML in your case....

Comment: Library method is capturing the exception and does not contain a throw method.   An exception can only be caught once (unless throw is used) so your code is not getting the exception.  I believe the client error message is wrong and I would trust the error you are getting on the server indicating the credentials are correct. Are you using a two step authentication?  Step one is to get a token.  Step 2 is the actual query.  The XML is the results of step 2.  I think the error "
There is an error in XML document (1, 2181004)" is occurring in step 1 instead of step 2.  Where is code for step 2.

Comment: @Luuk Thank you, I'll investigate on it. Maybe I may use browser instead of my code to "see" the result.

Comment: @jdweng It's not two step authentication. We just return an array from the web service function and the remainder (converting it to an XML response) is done by the SOAP itself.

Comment: You said "This function is located in Reference.cs which is automatically generated by the Visual Studio".  Probably the automatic code is using two step authentication.

Comment: Maybe. I've no idea.